# Pandas remove square brackets from entire dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

If there a way to remove square brackets from my dataframe? I have tried

```
df.replace({'[', ''},regex=True)
```

but it doesnt appear to remove them.

DataFrame:

```
datasource                            platforms permissions
['Windows event logs']              ['Windows'] ['User', 'Administrator']
['Process command-line parameters'] ['Windows'] ['User']
```

There are more columns that have the square brackets the above is just an example of some of the columns. Again some columns/rows contain the square brackets and some dont. Is there a way to search the dataframe and remove them if they are there?

I know I am able to carry this out by doing

```
new_df['platforms'] = new_df['platforms'].astype(str)
new_df['platforms'] = new_df['platforms'].str.strip(']')
new_df['platforms'] = new_df['platforms'].str.strip('[')
```

but as there are multiple columns with this i was wondering if there was a way to do it across the entire dataframe.

I have printed the type of the columns shown above out (before they get converted to a string) and the type comes back as the following:

```
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
```

Comment: `[` and `]` denotes that value is `list`

Comment: When I print the type of the column Platforms for example it says its "<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>"

Comment: `pandas.core.series.Series` represent single column of `pandas.DataFrame` not single element (*cell*)